# How to use RedisJSON properly as a relational db?

Tags: redis, redisjson

I am using RedisJSON as module on top of Redis and I wonder how I can use a javascript object properly as a relational database.

Comment: Redis is not a relational database, it is a key-value database.

Comment: @usuario that's why I asked how we can use it as a relational db and I know it can be used as one.